# Why "Save as" and "Export" is not working in my menu?

Tags: python, scripting, pie-menu

In this small menu example below, I'd like to know why "Save as" and "Export" are not working on my menu?

How am I supposed to save as inside of a menu?

What am I doing wrong ?

```
bl_info = {
    "name" : "Back Me Up [BD3D]", 
    "author" : "BD3D",   
    "description" : "Save like you never did before.",
    "blender" : (2, 80, 0),
    "location" : "Ctrl S, Operator",
    "warning" : "",
    "category" : "Generic"
}

import bpy
from bpy.types import Menu
import bpy
context = bpy.context

class VIEW3D_PIE_backmeuptradnormal(Menu): #problem first save and save as ? what ???????????????????????
    bl_label = ""
    bl_idname = "view3d.menu_normal_backmeup" #other id if two pies 

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        pie = layout
        pie.operator("wm.collada_export",text="export not working",  icon='BLENDER')
        pie.operator("wm.save_as_mainfile",text="save as not working",  icon='BLENDER')

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_PIE_backmeuptradnormal)
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_PIE_backmeuptradnormal)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu(name="view3d.menu_normal_backmeup")
```

-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pie.operator_context = 'INVOKE_DEFAULT'
```

this line before the operator

```
pie.operator_context = 'EXEC_REGION_WIN'
```

and this line after will do it